# Change Locale not work after migrate to Androidx

Tags: android, android-activity, android-support-library, androidx

I have an old project that supports multi-languages. I want to upgrade support library and target platform, **Before migrating to `Androidx` everything works fine but now change language not work!**

I use this code to change default locale of App

```
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language)
{
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}
```

And call this method on each activity by override `attachBaseContext` like this:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase)
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String language = preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, "fa");
    super.attachBaseContext(updateResources(newBase, language));
}
```

I try other method to get string and I noticed that ‍‍‍‍`getActivity().getBaseContext().getString` work and `getActivity().getString` not work. Even the following code does not work and always show `app_name` vlaue in default resource string.xml.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"/>
```

I share a sample code in https://github.com/Freydoonk/LanguageTest

Also `getActivity()..getResources().getIdentifier` not work and always return 0!

Comment: I think these kind of issues would be much easier to solve if you provide a sample app.

Comment: Do you recreate the activity after applying language change?

Comment: @mustafiz012 If I call recareate in attachBaseContext make a circular call and ...

Comment: @IbrahimAli I share a sample code in https://github.com/Freydoonk/LanguageTest

Comment: Interestingly, setting `android:configChanges="uiMode"` resolves the issue, but then instead, naturally, we get color artifacts when changing between light and dark theme ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, I find the problem in my app. When migrating the project to `Androidx` dependencies of my project changed like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
}
```

As it is seen, version of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` is `1.1.0-alpha03` when I changed it to the latest stable version, `1.0.2`, my problem is resolved and the change language working properly.

I find the latest stable version of `appcompat` library in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat). I also change other libraries to the latest stable version.

Now my app dependencies section is like bellow:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. I already had stable `1.0.2` for `appcompat`, but my problem was in the design support library or `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06`. So when I switched to the stable `1.0.0`, it's fixed.

Answer (score 135):

**UPDATE Mar 15 2023:**

AppCompat 1.6.1 is out, but doesn't seem to break anything. Workaround below still works, yay!

**UPDATE Sep 5 2022:**

AppCompat 1.5.0 was released, which includes [these changes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#version_150_3), specifically:

> This stable version includes improvements to night mode stability
>
> [...]
>
> Fixes an issue where AppCompat’s context wrapper reused the application context's backing resource implementation, resulting in `uiMode` being overwritten on the application context. ([Idf9d5](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2137592))

Digging deeper inside the code reveals several crucial changes which essentially mean that, similar to before, if you're not using a `ContextWrapper` or `ContextThemeWrapper` AND *don't offer users to set a different night mode than they've set on their device* THEN all context wrapping and theming and locale updates *should* now work properly and you *should* be able to safely remove all your workarounds explained below or any other hacks you might have in place.

Unfortunately, if you're using any kind of `ContextWrapper` OR allowing users to manually set the night mode of your app, then there still seem to be issues, I'm not sure why Google has such trouble fixing this. The problem I've faced: If `uiMode` is NOT overwritten anymore, that means when you:

- set your device to dark mode,
- set your app to light mode (night mode disabled),
- rotate your phone to landscape,
- lock your screen,
- unlock your screen again while still in landscape,

then depending on your device and possibly Android version you may see the application context's `uiMode` being stale and ending up with awesome black on black and white on white theming glitches. This also happens for device in light mode and app in night mode. In addition,  your app's locale may be reset to the device locale. In these cases you need to use the solution described below.

**Working solution for AppCompat 1.2.0-1.6.1 when encountering issues with locale or day/night:**

If you use a `ContextWrapper` or `ContextThemeWrapper` inside `attachBaseContext` in AppCompat 1.2.0-1.4.2, locale changes will break, because when you pass your wrapped context to super,

1. the 1.2.0-1.4.2 `AppCompatActivity` makes internal calls which wrap your `ContextWrapper` in another `ContextThemeWrapper` and `AppCompatDelegateImpl` thus ending up in your locale being ignored,
2. or if you use a `ContextThemeWrapper`, overrides its configuration to a blank one, similar to what happened back in 1.1.0.

Whether you use a context wrapper or not in 1.5.0, as described in my latest update, there may still be theme glitches and app locale being reset. The solution either way is always the same, nothing else worked for me. The big obstacle is that, unlike in 1.1.0, `applyOverrideConfiguration` is called on your base context, not your host activity, so you can't just override that method in your activity and fix the locale (or `uiMode`) as you could in 1.1.0. The only working solution I'm aware of is to *reverse the wrapping by overriding `getDelegate()` to make sure your wrapping and/or locale override comes last*. First, you add the class below:

Kotlin sample (please note that the class MUST be inside the `androidx.appcompat.app` package because the only existing `AppCompatDelegate` constructor is package private)

```
package androidx.appcompat.app

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

class BaseContextWrappingDelegate(private val superDelegate: AppCompatDelegate) : AppCompatDelegate() {

    override fun getSupportActionBar() = superDelegate.supportActionBar

    override fun setSupportActionBar(toolbar: Toolbar?) = superDelegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    override fun getMenuInflater(): MenuInflater? = superDelegate.menuInflater

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        superDelegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        removeActivityDelegate(superDelegate)
        addActiveDelegate(this)
    }

    override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = superDelegate.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) = superDelegate.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)

    override fun onStart() = superDelegate.onStart()

    override fun onStop() = superDelegate.onStop()

    override fun onPostResume() = superDelegate.onPostResume()

    override fun setTheme(themeResId: Int) = superDelegate.setTheme(themeResId)

    override fun <T : View?> findViewById(id: Int) = superDelegate.findViewById<T>(id)

    override fun setContentView(v: View?) = superDelegate.setContentView(v)

    override fun setContentView(resId: Int) = superDelegate.setContentView(resId)

    override fun setContentView(v: View?, lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) = superDelegate.setContentView(v, lp)

    override fun addContentView(v: View?, lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) = superDelegate.addContentView(v, lp)

    override fun attachBaseContext2(context: Context) = wrap(superDelegate.attachBaseContext2(super.attachBaseContext2(context)))

    override fun setTitle(title: CharSequence?) = superDelegate.setTitle(title)

    override fun invalidateOptionsMenu() = superDelegate.invalidateOptionsMenu()

    override fun onDestroy() {
        superDelegate.onDestroy()
        removeActivityDelegate(this)
    }

    override fun getDrawerToggleDelegate() = superDelegate.drawerToggleDelegate

    override fun requestWindowFeature(featureId: Int) = superDelegate.requestWindowFeature(featureId)

    override fun hasWindowFeature(featureId: Int) = superDelegate.hasWindowFeature(featureId)

    override fun startSupportActionMode(callback: ActionMode.Callback) = superDelegate.startSupportActionMode(callback)

    override fun installViewFactory() = superDelegate.installViewFactory()

    override fun createView(parent: View?, name: String?, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? = superDelegate.createView(parent, name, context, attrs)

    override fun setHandleNativeActionModesEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        superDelegate.isHandleNativeActionModesEnabled = enabled
    }

    override fun isHandleNativeActionModesEnabled() = superDelegate.isHandleNativeActionModesEnabled

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) = superDelegate.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    override fun applyDayNight() = superDelegate.applyDayNight()

    override fun setLocalNightMode(mode: Int) {
        superDelegate.localNightMode = mode
    }

    override fun getLocalNightMode() = superDelegate.localNightMode

    private fun wrap(context: Context): Context {
        TODO("your wrapping implementation here")
    }
}
```

Then inside our base activity class (make sure you remove any other previous workarounds first) add this code:

```
private var baseContextWrappingDelegate: AppCompatDelegate? = null

override fun getDelegate() = baseContextWrappingDelegate ?: BaseContextWrappingDelegate(super.getDelegate()).apply {
    baseContextWrappingDelegate = this
}

// OPTIONAL createConfigurationContext and/or onStart code below may be needed depending on your ContextWrapper implementation to avoid issues with themes

override fun createConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration: Configuration) : Context {
    val context = super.createConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration)
    TODO("your wrapping implementation here")
}

private fun fixStaleConfiguration() {
    // we only want to fix the configuration if our app theme is different than the system theme, otherwise it will result in an infinite configuration change loop causing a StackOverflowError and crashing your app
    if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() != AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
        applicationContext?.configuration?.uiMode = resources.configuration.uiMode
    TODO("your locale updating implementation here")
    // OPTIONAL if you are using a context wrapper, the wrapper might have stale resources with wrong uiMode and/or locale which you need to clear or update at this stage
}

override fun onRestart() {
    fixStaleConfiguration()
    super.onRestart()
}

// OPTIONAL if you have specified configChanges in your manifest, especially orientation and uiMode
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    fixStaleConfiguration()
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
}
```

For an example how to successfully "clear stale resources", which may or may not be needed in your case:

```
(context as? ContextThemeWrapper)?.run {
    if (mContextThemeWrapperResources == null) {
        mContextThemeWrapperResources = ContextThemeWrapper::class.java.getDeclaredField("mResources")
        mContextThemeWrapperResources!!.isAccessible = true
    }
    mContextThemeWrapperResources!!.set(this, null)
} ?: (context as? androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper)?.run {
    if (mAppCompatContextThemeWrapperResources == null) {
        mAppCompatContextThemeWrapperResources = androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper::class.java.getDeclaredField("mResources")
        mAppCompatContextThemeWrapperResources!!.isAccessible = true
    }
    mAppCompatContextThemeWrapperResources!!.set(this, null)
}
(context as? AppCompatActivity)?.run {
    if (mAppCompatActivityResources == null) {
        mAppCompatActivityResources = AppCompatActivity::class.java.getDeclaredField("mResources")
        mAppCompatActivityResources!!.isAccessible = true
    }
    mAppCompatActivityResources!!.set(this, null)
}
```

**OLD ANSWER AND CONFIRMED WORKING SOLUTION FOR APPCOMPAT 1.1.0:**

Basically what's happening in the background is that while you've set the configuration correctly in `attachBaseContext`, the `AppCompatDelegateImpl` then goes and overrides the configuration to a *completely fresh configuration without a locale*:

```
 final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 conf.uiMode = newNightMode | (conf.uiMode & ~Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK);

 try {
     ...
     ((android.view.ContextThemeWrapper) mHost).applyOverrideConfiguration(conf);
     handled = true;
 } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     ...
 }
```

[In an unreleased commit by Chris Banes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/67f756b383344764f7d3539c5955fbe5f491a3ba) this was actually fixed: The new configuration is a deep copy of the base context's configuration.

```
final Configuration conf = new Configuration(baseConfiguration);
conf.uiMode = newNightMode | (conf.uiMode & ~Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK);
try {
    ...
    ((android.view.ContextThemeWrapper) mHost).applyOverrideConfiguration(conf);
    handled = true;
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    ...
}
```

Until this is released, it's possible to do the exact same thing manually. To continue using version 1.1.0 add this below your `attachBaseContext`:

**Kotlin solution**

```
override fun applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration: Configuration?) {
    if (overrideConfiguration != null) {
        val uiMode = overrideConfiguration.uiMode
        overrideConfiguration.setTo(baseContext.resources.configuration)
        overrideConfiguration.uiMode = uiMode
    }
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration)
}
```

**Java solution**

```
@Override
public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
    if (overrideConfiguration != null) {
        int uiMode = overrideConfiguration.uiMode;
        overrideConfiguration.setTo(getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
        overrideConfiguration.uiMode = uiMode;
    }
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
}
```

This code does exactly the same what `Configuration(baseConfiguration)` does under the hood, but because we are doing it *after* the `AppCompatDelegate` has already set the correct `uiMode`, we have to make sure to take the overridden `uiMode` over to after we fix it so we don't lose the dark/light mode setting.

***Please note*** that this only works by itself if you don't specify `configChanges="uiMode"` inside your manifest. If you do, then there's yet another bug: Inside `onConfigurationChanged` the `newConfig.uiMode` won't be set by `AppCompatDelegateImpl`'s `onConfigurationChanged`. This can be fixed as well if you copy all the code `AppCompatDelegateImpl` uses to calculate the current night mode to your base activity code and then override it before the `super.onConfigurationChanged` call. In Kotlin it would look like this:

```
private var activityHandlesUiMode = false
private var activityHandlesUiModeChecked = false

private val isActivityManifestHandlingUiMode: Boolean
    get() {
        if (!activityHandlesUiModeChecked) {
            val pm = packageManager ?: return false
            activityHandlesUiMode = try {
                val info = pm.getActivityInfo(ComponentName(this, javaClass), 0)
                info.configChanges and ActivityInfo.CONFIG_UI_MODE != 0
            } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                false
            }
        }
        activityHandlesUiModeChecked = true
        return activityHandlesUiMode
    }

override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    if (isActivityManifestHandlingUiMode) {
        val nightMode = if (delegate.localNightMode != AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED) 
            delegate.localNightMode
        else
            AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()
        val configNightMode = when (nightMode) {
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES -> Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO -> Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO
            else -> applicationContext.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
        }
        newConfig.uiMode = configNightMode or (newConfig.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK.inv())
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
}
```

Comment: It worked perfect for me. Thanks! But, i didn't undestand how overriding "applyOverrideConfiguration" method solves the problem. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @Burak If you check the source code of ContextThemeWrapper you should be able to see that whatever is passed to super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration) is stored and later used to fetch any kind of resources. That's just the way Google implemented the day/night theming. The base resource configuration doesn't have the correct uiMode setting, so ContextThemeWrapper overrides getResources() to return an instance where the configuration has it.

Comment: Yes from 1.2.0, `applyOverrideConfiguration` is not getting called. You have to call this function manually from `attachBaseContext`

Comment: In case it might be of help to anyone, [here](https://github.com/CNugteren/NLWeer/pull/20/files) is a full diff of a working locale change implementation based on combining this answer with [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630533) using an AppCompatActivity activity and library version 1.2.0.

Comment: thanks for the update of appCompat 1.2.0, love you.

Comment: Finally found an answer that works for me, I've been working on this for days and was not able to get it to work; this is great. Thank you very much for this excellent answer

Comment: This works with AppCompat 1.3.0-beta01 also!

Answer (score 13):

There is an issue in new app compat libraries related to night mode that is causing to override the configuration on android 21 to 25.
This can be fixed by applying your configuration when this public function is called:

> public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration

For me, this little trick has worked by copying the settings from the overridden configuration to my configuration but you can do whatever you want. It is better to reapply  your language logic to the new configuration to minimize errors

```
@Override
public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21&& Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 25) {
        //Use you logic to update overrideConfiguration locale
        Locale locale = getLocale()//your own implementation here;
        overrideConfiguration.setLocale(locale);
    }
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: this code change makes crash in multiple places on some devices `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.Locale.toString()' on a null object reference
android.widget.Editor$TextActionModeCallback.populateMenuWithItemsExt`. It is better adviced to downgrade or follow @0101100101's answer..

Comment: getLocale and setLocale should be on [Android N/24 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/2199894)

Answer (score 10):

I am using "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01" but I suppose it will also work on [Version 1.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.2.0).
The following code is based on [Android Code Search](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:appcompat/appcompat/src/androidTest/java/androidx/appcompat/app/NightModeCustomApplyOverrideConfigurationActivity.java).

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.*

open class MyBaseActivity :AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
        val config = Configuration()
        applyOverrideConfiguration(config)
    }

    override fun applyOverrideConfiguration(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.applyOverrideConfiguration(updateConfigurationIfSupported(newConfig))
    }

    open fun updateConfigurationIfSupported(config: Configuration): Configuration? {
        // Configuration.getLocales is added after 24 and Configuration.locale is deprecated in 24
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            if (!config.locales.isEmpty) {
                return config
            }
        } else {
            if (config.locale != null) {
                return config
            }
        }
        // Please Get your language code from some storage like shared preferences
        val languageCode = "fa"
        val locale = Locale(languageCode)
        if (locale != null) {
            // Configuration.setLocale is added after 17 and Configuration.locale is deprecated
            // after 24
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                config.setLocale(locale)
            } else {
                config.locale = locale
            }
        }
        return config
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the most simple answer that solves my issue, thank! @EhsanShadi

I'll just wait for 1.3.0 updates to what will happen then, :)

Comment: How's this one works? creating new configuration overrides all the pre defined configurations and breaks the ui.

Comment: @dor506 what kind of UI breakages are you experiencing? This seems to be the only solution that has worked for me androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha03 but would be happy to know some of the caveat to be prepared for release. Thanks

Comment: @saintjab Take a look at 0101100101 latest update (aug 20), which actually does work while updating the current configuration (context.getResources().getConfiguration()), instead of create new configuration in every activity.

Answer (score 8):

Late answer but I thought might be helpful. As of *androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01* The solution of [0101100101](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004553/1503157) overriding `applyOverrideConfiguration` no longer works on me. Instead, in then overriden `attacheBaseContext`, you have to call the `applyOverrideConfiguration()` **without overriding it**.

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    val newContext = LocaleHelper.getUpdatedContext(newBase)
    super.attachBaseContext(newContext)
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1){
        applyOverrideConfiguration(newContext.resources.configuration)
    }
}
```

It's just a shame that his solution only works on 1.1.0. Base on my research this should have been officially fix. It's just weird that this bug still here. I know I use the beta but for someone who wants to use the latest, this solution for me is working.
Tested on emulator api level 21-25. Above that api level, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me for androidx.appcompat...1.2.0 otherwise locale change was not happening in some phones (samsung s5 in my case)
Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Finally i got solution for locate, In my case actually issue was with `bundle apk`  because it split the locate files. In `bundle apk` by default all splits will be generated. but within the android block of your `build.gradle` file you are able to declare which splits will be generated.

```
bundle {
            language {
                // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
                // configuration APKs for language resources. These
                // resources are instead packaged with each base and
                // dynamic feature APK.
                enableSplit = false
            }
        }
```

After adding this code to **android block of `build.gradle`** file my issue get resolved.

Comment: I was having the same issue. When I used to check before publishing on play store, everything worked and after publishing the locale change did not work. I applied this solution and now works flawlessly. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem. Whenever I install debug version it was working but when I release bundle had the issue and tried alot of solution but this is the only one that worked. Thanks.

Comment: This! It makes so much sense. One of the testing phones never displayed the selected language from the app and we wondered why it only happens when it's downloaded from Google Play. I verified it working by adding the system language -> clear data -> restarting the app. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` bug can also be resolved by simply calling `getResources()` in `Activity.applyOverrideConfiguration()`

```
@Override public void
applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration cfgOverride)
{
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP &&
      Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    // add this to fix androidx.appcompat:appcompat 1.1.0 bug
    // which happens on Android 6.x ~ 7.x
    getResources();
  }

  super.applyOverrideConfiguration(cfgOverride);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final float CUSTOM_FONT_SCALE = 4.24f;
    public static final Locale CUSTOM_LOCALE = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH; // or whatever

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(useCustomConfig(newBase));
    }

    private Context useCustomConfig(Context context) {
        Locale.setDefault(CUSTOM_LOCALE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.fontScale = CUSTOM_FONT_SCALE;
            config.setLocale(CUSTOM_LOCALE);
            return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
            config.fontScale = CUSTOM_FONT_SCALE;
            config.locale = CUSTOM_LOCALE;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
            return context;
        }
    }
}
```

Sources: [issuetracker comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155685118#comment2) and the [first sample linked from the issuetracker comment](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:appcompat/appcompat/src/androidTest/java/androidx/appcompat/app/NightModeCustomAttachBaseContextActivity.java;l=34).

Whilst the above is working fine for me, another option from the [second sample linked from the issuetracker comment](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:appcompat/appcompat/src/androidTest/java/androidx/appcompat/app/NightModeCustomApplyOverrideConfigurationActivity.java;l=33) is as follows (I haven't personally tried this out):

```
@RequiresApi(17)
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final float CUSTOM_FONT_SCALE = 4.24f;
    public static final Locale CUSTOM_LOCALE = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH; // or whatever

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.fontScale = CUSTOM_FONT_SCALE;
        applyOverrideConfiguration(config);
    }

    @Override
    public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.applyOverrideConfiguration(updateConfigurationIfSupported(newConfig));
    }

    private Configuration updateConfigurationIfSupported(Configuration config) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            if (!config.getLocales().isEmpty()) {
                return config;
            }
        } else {
            if (config.locale != null) {
                return config;
            }
        }

        Locale locale = CUSTOM_LOCALE;
        if (locale != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                config.setLocale(locale);
            } else {
                config.locale = locale;
            }
        }
        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: `config.setLocale(locale);` should be on Android N (24) or above.

Answer (score 3):

Now the language does not change with these libraries:
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0,
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0

The problem was only solved in this library:
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-rc01

Comment: Hey is it good to use 1.3.0-rc01 version instead of 1.2.0 in production level release?

Comment: yes, it's good. Otherwise, 1.2.0 not working at all. 
In my case there was troubles with Application context, but all was good with Activity context.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a newer version that also works:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

As @Fred mentioned `appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03` has a glitch although it's not mentioned on their [release versions log](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat)

Comment: I test `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04`, It has this problem yet.

Comment: for my production app works just fine, I use a custom implementation for  `ContextWrapper` within `attachBaseContext(Context newBase)` for each activity

Answer (score 0):

Had the same bug on `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`. Switched to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01` and now langs change on `Android 5-6.`

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @0101100101 worked for me.

Only that I used

```
@Override
public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration)
{
  if (overrideConfiguration != null) {
    int uiMode = overrideConfiguration.uiMode;
    overrideConfiguration.setTo(getResources().getConfiguration());
    overrideConfiguration.uiMode = uiMode;
  }
  super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
}
```

so only `getResources()` instead of `getBaseContext().getResources()`.

In my case I have extended ContextWrapper with overridden getResources().
But after applyOverrideConfiguration is called I can't access my custom getResources. I get standard ones instead.

If I use the code above everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In the App level Gradle, I included the following code within the android division,

```
bundle {
    language {
        // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
        // configuration APKs for language resources. These
        // resources are instead packaged with each base and
        // dynamic feature APK.
        enableSplit = false
    }
}
```

https://medium.com/dwarsoft/how-to-provide-languages-dynamically-using-app-bundle-567d2ec32be6

Answer (score -2):

**1. Method you may use in *attachBaseContext()***

```
private void setLanguage(Context mContext, String localeName) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(localeName);
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }
```

**2. Override in activities**

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    setLanguage(newBase, "your language");
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
}
```

**NB:** This is working fine for me after I recreate the activity

Comment: Where you call 'recreate();`

Comment: Suppose, you use a button click to change language. In that case, when you click the button, put your language in shared Preferences and recreate your activity. Get language string from shared Preferences when necessary. If you require more detail, I'll share code example.

Comment: I do this, I persist selected language in shared Preferences and recreate the app, I get selected language from shared Preferences and pass to `setLanguage(newBase, myPpersistedLanguage);` in `attachBaseContext` but this is not work. I edit an complete `attachBaseContext` in sample code in my question to show this.

Comment: I think your strings.xml file aren't configured as it requires. If you please tell me, do you have alternative strings.xml file?? For example: strings.xml, strings.xml (fa)

Comment: I add a screenshot of my resource in my project

Comment: Then I'm gonna share my working code example. Please allow me some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190386/discussion-between-mustafiz012-and-fred).