# After updating AppCompat library to appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03 Locale configuration is not working anymore

Tags: android, locale, android-appcompat

After updating

`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'`

to

`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'`

locale settings was not working anymore, spent half day to figure out that library was the actual problem.

Is there another NEW way for locale setting or workaround, or is it just a bug in the library and should just wait for another version with bugfix?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265834/change-locale-not-work-after-migrate-to-androidx

Comment: It's a bug, check this for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58777775/6247186

Comment: It is fixed in newer versions