# Migrating from AppCompat 1.1 to AppCompat 1.2

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Updating to AppCompat 1.2 is not setting the locale change inside the app.
I am changing the locale programmatically.

When migrating from 1.0 -> 1.1 ([This Helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900554/language-change-issue-after-updating-to-androidx-appcompatappcompat1-1-0))

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does 'breaking' mean? An exception?

Comment: I am setting the locale programmatically based on the user input, but the locale change is not reflecting.