# changes in locale does work when add many modules

Tags: android, kotlin, locale, android-context, crowdin

The Locale does work when have many modules.

Context:

- We use Crowdin (this lib apply a wrapper above context)
- The app works perfectly when only is a single module
- Use Appcompat:1.2
- When Change the locale works

but, when i add a new module in `app` the change locale does work. `implementation project(":newmodule")`

When is **Single Module**:

- `BaseContext` = **`CrowdinContextWrapper`**

When is **Multi Module**:

- `BaseContext` = **`ContextThemeWrapper`**

---

`Activity` extended **`BaseActivity`**

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Crowdin.forceUpdate(context = this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(Crowdin.wrapContext(Localization.wrap(context = newBase)))
    }
}
```

```
class Localization(base: Context) : ContextThemeWrapper(base, R.style.AppTheme) {
    companion object {

        fun wrap(context: Context, language: String = "es", country: String = "MX"): ContextThemeWrapper {
            var ctx = context
            val config = context.resources.configuration

            if (language != "") {
                val locale = Locale(language, country)
                Locale.setDefault(locale)
                config.setLocale(locale)
                // Used setLayoutDirection for RTL and LTR
                config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
                ctx = context.createConfigurationContext(config)

            }

            return Localization(ctx)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add extra information about the problem. your code body is good but I think your statements about single module and multi module is not enough. if you add some extra information, this will help developers to help you better .

Comment: I solved this problem and its relate with Appcompat:1.2.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004553/3741698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

The problem is related to `Appcompat`. There are two different fixes depending on the version of `AppCompat`. Since you are using `1.2.0`, you will have to implement that one.

`AppCompatDelegateImpl` ends up removing the locale, because essentially a [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper) wraps your [ContextWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper). See the implementation @ [AppCompatDelegateImpl.java line 368](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java#368) . Also lines [388](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java#388), and [480](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java#480).

```
try {
                ContextThemeWrapperCompatApi17Impl.applyOverrideConfiguration(
                        (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper) baseContext, config);
                return baseContext;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to apply configuration to base context", e);
                }
            }
```

The work-around for this is to over-ride `getDelegate` inside your Base Activity like this:

```
private var baseContextWrappingDelegate: AppCompatDelegate? = null

override fun getDelegate() = baseContextWrappingDelegate ?: BaseContextWrappingDelegate(super.getDelegate()).apply {
    baseContextWrappingDelegate = this
}
```

And you also need the following class ( see : [Change Locale not work after migrate to Androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265834/change-locale-not-work-after-migrate-to-androidx/58004553#58004553) ).

```
package androidx.appcompat.app

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

class BaseContextWrappingDelegate(private val superDelegate: AppCompatDelegate) : AppCompatDelegate() {

    override fun getSupportActionBar() = superDelegate.supportActionBar

    override fun setSupportActionBar(toolbar: Toolbar?) = superDelegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    override fun getMenuInflater(): MenuInflater? = superDelegate.menuInflater

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        superDelegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        removeActivityDelegate(superDelegate)
        addActiveDelegate(this)
    }

    override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = superDelegate.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) = superDelegate.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)

    override fun onStart() = superDelegate.onStart()

    override fun onStop() = superDelegate.onStop()

    override fun onPostResume() = superDelegate.onPostResume()

    override fun setTheme(themeResId: Int) = superDelegate.setTheme(themeResId)

    override fun <T : View?> findViewById(id: Int) = superDelegate.findViewById<T>(id)

    override fun setContentView(v: View?) = superDelegate.setContentView(v)

    override fun setContentView(resId: Int) = superDelegate.setContentView(resId)

    override fun setContentView(v: View?, lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) = superDelegate.setContentView(v, lp)

    override fun addContentView(v: View?, lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) = superDelegate.addContentView(v, lp)

    override fun attachBaseContext2(context: Context) = wrap(superDelegate.attachBaseContext2(super.attachBaseContext2(context)))

    override fun setTitle(title: CharSequence?) = superDelegate.setTitle(title)

    override fun invalidateOptionsMenu() = superDelegate.invalidateOptionsMenu()

    override fun onDestroy() {
        superDelegate.onDestroy()
        removeActivityDelegate(this)
    }

    override fun getDrawerToggleDelegate() = superDelegate.drawerToggleDelegate

    override fun requestWindowFeature(featureId: Int) = superDelegate.requestWindowFeature(featureId)

    override fun hasWindowFeature(featureId: Int) = superDelegate.hasWindowFeature(featureId)

    override fun startSupportActionMode(callback: ActionMode.Callback) = superDelegate.startSupportActionMode(callback)

    override fun installViewFactory() = superDelegate.installViewFactory()

    override fun createView(parent: View?, name: String?, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? = superDelegate.createView(parent, name, context, attrs)

    override fun setHandleNativeActionModesEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        superDelegate.isHandleNativeActionModesEnabled = enabled
    }

    override fun isHandleNativeActionModesEnabled() = superDelegate.isHandleNativeActionModesEnabled

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) = superDelegate.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    override fun applyDayNight() = superDelegate.applyDayNight()

    override fun setLocalNightMode(mode: Int) {
        superDelegate.localNightMode = mode
    }

    override fun getLocalNightMode() = superDelegate.localNightMode

    private fun wrap(context: Context): Context {
        //Put wrapping implementation here
    }
}
```

### References

1. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java#368
2. [Change Locale not work after migrate to Androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265834/change-locale-not-work-after-migrate-to-androidx/)
3. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java#368